# Moving Complex Query Results to a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex query that cannot be saved as a view because of the `DECLARE` statements at the beginning of the query.

I would like to save the results of the query into a table.

I tried to insert the following statement to surround the whole query and also only around the `SET @sql` and `EXEC(@sql)`.

Both caused errors that I could not resolve.

This is the query that produces the results I need:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colList VARCHAR(MAX)

--create dynamic list of columns
SELECT @colList = STUFF((SELECT + ',' + QUOTENAME(colName +  CAST(CAST(Billing_Order AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR))
                         FROM Credible_Client_Insurance_Raw_Data
                         CROSS APPLY
                             (SELECT 1 As Ord, 'Payer_ID' ColName 
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT 2 As Ord, 'Billing_Order' 
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT 3 As Ord, 'Insurance_ID' 
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT 4 As Ord, 'Group_No' 
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT 5 As Ord, 'Copay_Fee' 
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT 6 As Ord, 'Start_Date') v 
                          GROUP BY colName, Ord, CAST(CAST(Billing_Order AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR)
                          ORDER BY CAST(CAST(Billing_Order AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR), Ord
                          FOR XML PAT(''), TYPE).value('/', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

--unpivot columns into rows and then apply pivot
SET @sql = 'SELECT Client_ID, ' + @colList + ' 
            FROM 
                (SELECT  
                     Client_ID, ColVal,
                     colName + CAST(CAST(Billing_Order AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR) ColName
                 FROM Credible_Client_Insurance_Raw_Data
                 CROSS APPLY
   (
     SELECT Payer_ID As ColVal, ''Payer_ID'' ColName UNION ALL
     SELECT Billing_Order, ''Billing_Order'' UNION ALL
     SELECT Insurance_ID, ''Insurance_ID'' UNION ALL
     SELECT Group_No, ''Group_No'' UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(Copay_Fee AS VARCHAR), ''Copay_Fee'' UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(Start_Date AS VARCHAR), ''Start_Date'' 
   ) v 
) A
PIVOT
(
   MAX(ColVal) FOR ColName IN (' + @colList + ')
) P1 '


EXEC(@sql)
```

I just want to INSERT the query's result set into a permanent table `Credible_Client_Insurance_Data`.

Is there any way to essentially perform a

```
INSERT INTO Credible_Client_Insurance_Data (Client_ID, etc.)
    SELECT Client_ID, etc.
    FROM query_results
```

Or some type of data insert into the table?

Comment: are columns in `@colList` different from the columns in `Credible_Client_Insurance_Data` ? could you give a sample on that.

Comment: *"This is the query that produces the results I need:"* your sure that query runs ? `FOR XML PAT('')` -> `FOR XML PATH('')`

Comment: The Columns in the Query have slightly different names from the Query
Client_ID is the Same but Payer_ID1 is First_Payer_ID

Comment: Yes I am sure that this query runs.
not sure exactly why, Copied code and modified to my fields.

Comment: Worked perfectly with one modification to INSERT

Added, added Client_ID to INSERT LIST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** I'm understanding correctly, don't you just need to change the value of `@sql` to:

```
SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO Credible_Client_Insurance_Data (' + @colList + ')
SELECT Client_ID, ' + @colList + ' 
FROM
(
   SELECT Client_ID, ColVal,
   colName +  CAST(CAST(Billing_Order AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR) ColName
   FROM Credible_Client_Insurance_Raw_Data
   CROSS APPLY
   (
     SELECT Payer_ID As ColVal, ''Payer_ID'' ColName UNION ALL
     SELECT Billing_Order, ''Billing_Order'' UNION ALL
     SELECT Insurance_ID, ''Insurance_ID'' UNION ALL
     SELECT Group_No, ''Group_No'' UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(Copay_Fee AS VARCHAR), ''Copay_Fee'' UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(Start_Date AS VARCHAR), ''Start_Date'' 
   ) v 
) A
PIVOT
(
   MAX(ColVal) FOR ColName IN (' + @colList + ')
) P1 ;';
```

Comment: That comment appears incomplete.

Comment: The Area around   )  P1 ; ' ; seems to not quite be correct

I believe that there should be a close ) after P1 to associate with the Open ( associated with the FROM the INSERT SELECT

I Placed it after P1 and change it multiple times including the ;'s and etc.

Always an received an error. Amy Suggestions.

Comment: `'...) P1'` was what you had in your query, HoganS. All I did was properly terminate the statements (thus `'... ) p1;';`. If things aren't working, then your query wasn't before, or the columns in `Credible_Client_Insurance_Data` don't have that of the columns in `@ColList`. I can't see your data, and I have no errors, so i can't help you.

Comment: Thank You Got It, had to add Client_Id to the Insert Statement